# "Not Start With" query in Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to implement "not startwith" query in appengine more efficently?

it should be something like this:

```
Select * from Table A where name not like 'CON%'.
```

Datastore contains around 100K entity and 40% of entities are startwith `CON`. Performing an iteration on this table to get the each entity name and adding some task for them. And i need to ignore those entity name startwith `CON`.

Comment: Perform two queries, one with 'name < "CON"' and another with 'name > "CON"', and combine the results.

Comment: @JasonHall As i said, Datastore contain around 100K entity. With th e help of Cursor, i'm iterate through these result.

Comment: Is this a one off or something you need to do all the time ?

Comment: @TimHoffman One time process.

Comment: Given it's a one time process, keep it simple. Perform your processing in a task (you may well need to chain tasks) or via remote_api.  100K isn't too bad via remote api especially if you work with 1000 items in each fetch.  Then run the job as two independent queries , based on the two queries in the other answer. In both cases you will need a cursor.

Comment: Using the remote api shell will mean you don't deploy new code and  you won't need to chain tasks and can let it run for ages.  If you don't do big fetches it can cost a lot in small transactions.

Comment: Thanks @TimHoffman . I was implemented this using chain of task. Will try reomte api.

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter` with `<`, `>=`:

```
import itertools
objs = itertools.chain(
    Model.all().filter('name <', 'CON'),
    Model.all().filter('name >=', 'COO')
)
for obj in objs:
    # do something with obj
```

Comment: Getting Error: `BadFilterError: invalid filter: Only one property per query may have inequality filters (<, <=, >=, >)..`

Comment: thank you. Aswer is corret. But As i said, Datastore contain around 100K entity. With th e help of Cursor, i'm iterate through these result. So how do i implement this ?

Comment: Given there is 100K+ records this is on the right track but it won't scale.  You need to use cursors, and merge the results.